# BroadcastReceiver (Manifest registered) lifecycle

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

My question is how `BroadcastReceiver` lifecycle corresponds to App lifecycle?

For example, we have `BroadcastReceiver` registered in Manifest which listens to the push notification, the App is dead, then I receive push notification.
In what order those methods will be invoked:

1. App.onCreate.
2. BroadcastReceiver.onReceive

Answer (score 0):

A broadcast receiver which is on the manifest is always active and it works even when the activity is not running.
Only receivers that are defined and registered dinamically do work only when app is running( such as [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html))

Comment: My question was not if it will be invoked, rather in what order those methods will be invoked.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers). The broadcast is registered and the system launches app if it's not launched when the broadcast is sent. Read the section I gave you.